# Generate seperate build file for a particular component in angular 7

Tags: angular7, angular-components, angular-builder

I am going to develop a very large application using Angular 7 Framework.

I have created a blank angular workspace using

```
 ng new angular-app --create-application=false
```

And in this workspace I have two angular applications created using the following commands:

```
 ng generate application app-one

 ng generate application app-two
```

Inside each of the two applications, I am going to have multiple components each working independently of each other.

I am looking for a way to **create a separate javascript build file for each of the component** so as to reduce the build size.

And use each of the separately build js files to use each component as a web component.

Please read what I have already tried to get a better idea.

I have tried the following steps:

1. Create a repository with prefix custom for custom angular elements:

   ng new app-name --prefix custom
2. Add the angular elements package:

   ng add @angular/elements
3. Create custom element component with encapsulation as native/emulated/none as required:

   ng g component my-component --inline-style --inline-template -v Native
4. Define the custom element in app.modulte.ts

```
    import  { Injector} from '@angular/core';
       import  { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
        ...
        export class AppModule {
            constructor(private injector : Injector){
            const el = createCustomElement(MyComponent, {injector : this.injector});
            customElements.define('my-component',el);
    }
            ngDoBootstrap(){ }
        }
```

5. Install ngx-build-plus package for building a single bundle (e. g. for Angular Elements):

   npm i ngx-build-plus
6. Update application's builder section within the angular.json file so that it points to ngx-build-plus:

   "builder": "ngx-build-plus:build",
7. Add script in package.json to run builder:

   "build:ngx": "ng build --prod  --output-hashing none --single-bundle true"
8. If required, Combine scripts.js and main.js in the created dist folder by creating a js file "concat_ngx.js":

```
     const fs = require('fs-extra');
        const concat = require('concat');
        (async function build() {
            const files = [
                './dist/<your_project>/scripts.js',
                './dist/<your_project>/main.js',
            ]
            await fs.ensureDir('elements_ngx')
            await concat(files, 'elements_ngx/combined-script.js');
        })()
```

7. Run file to get single js file:

   node concat_ngx.js
8. Use js file in any Angular/Other project to use the custom component created.

But the problem here is I have to change the component bootstrap every time in app-module.ts

I needed an automated way to change the bootstrapping in app-module.ts at runtime.

But the problem here is I have to change the component bootstrap every time in app-module.ts

I needed an automated way to change the bootstrapping in app-module.ts at runtime.

Comment: you able to achieve what you're looking for ?

Comment: yes @supercool, but not the way i would have liked it. Had to change my approach from component based architecture to application based architecture.

Comment: alright ! so if you split them as two projects you able to resolve dependency w.r.t build. please share your approach as answer so it might be helpful to anyone coming here.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 7, Add Default or Automatic bootstrapping :-

It is the default way an angular application bootstraps and main.ts holds the starting point of an application.

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

For more information see here: -https://medium.com/learnwithrahul/ways-of-bootstrapping-angular-applications-d379f594f604

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shilpa. 

But the issue that I was facing is how to automatize this bootstrapping processing as to create the build of different components I would have to manually change this piece of code every single time.

Comment: Apparently going forward I have to utilize the application system of angular 7 to get separate build. Sigh...

Answer (score 0):

```
ng serve -o app-one
or
ng serve -o app-two
```

For more information see here https://medium.com/@klauskpm/change-the-default-angular-project-27da8fca8721

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30615703)

Answer (score 0):

Declare standalone:true in component:

```
    @Component({
      standalone: true,
      selector: 'app-tour-list',
      templateUrl: './tour-list.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./tour-list.component.css']
    })
```

Use Routing like this:

```
    { path: 'TourList', loadComponent: () => import('./components/tour/tour-list/tour-list.component').then(m => m.TourListComponent) },
```